# Day of Month from DateField in Oracle

Tags: oracle, extract

I am trying to break up my ship date into various components so I can query it the way I need to. I am using the following code in my Oracle query:

```
EXTRACT (DAY FROM "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME") AS DofM,
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 1))) AS FY,
```

I am pulling the YEAR fine but I am getting an error every time I try to pull the DAY. It is telling me that I am missing a right parenthesis. Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the entire query (You will see in this query that I have been pulling the DayOfMonth as a character field - I am rewriting it now, trying to get it as a number. I just modified the extract month to do that and it works fine. I am going to work on the fiscal quarter next.):

```
SELECT
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTID" || ' - ' || "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAME" AS Customer,
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTID" || ' - ' || "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTDESCR" AS Product,
         SUM("AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."QNT1") AS Gallons,
         TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'MON') AS MonthName,
         TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'DD')  AS DayOfMonth,
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 1))) AS FY,
         EXTRACT (MONTH FROM(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 1))) AS FM,
         TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",1),'Q') AS FQ,
floor(
  (
  trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME") - 
  case 
  -- if December is current month, than use 1st of this month
  when to_char("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'MM') = 12 then trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'MM')
  -- else, use 1st December of previous year
  else add_months(trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'YYYY'), -1)
  end
  ) / 7
) + 1
AS FW,
         "FC_NAME"."LASTCONAME" AS SalesPerson ,
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO" AS InvoiceNumber,
         TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'mm/dd/yyyy') AS InvoiceDate,
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."COMMODITY" AS ProductCategory
    FROM "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW",   
         "AR_TRX_LINE",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER",   
         "AR_CUST",   
         "FC_NAME"  
   WHERE ( "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXHDRIDX" = "AR_TRX_HEADER"."ARTRXHDRIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXLINESEQ" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXLINESEQ" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXHDRIDX" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXHDRIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXLINETRXTYPE" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXLINETRXTYPE" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAMEIDX" = "AR_CUST"."CUSTNAMEIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_CUST"."SALESPERSONNAMEIDX" = "FC_NAME"."NAMEIDX" ) 
GROUP BY "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTDESCR",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAME",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTID",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTID",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."COMMODITY",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PSSIZE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."UOM",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."QNTTITLE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."AMTTITLE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SODATETIME",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SALESPERSON",   
         "FC_NAME"."LASTCONAME" 
ORDER BY "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME" ASC,   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO" ASC
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire query. Thanks.

Comment: Can you remove those two date select column and run the query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want me to do.

Answer (score 0):

To test chk with below query

```
 select EXTRACT (DAY FROM to_date('24-june-2016')) AS DOFM ,TO_CHAR(to_date('24-june-2016'), 'Day') from dual;
```

and then try with your query

```
select EXTRACT (DAY FROM "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME") AS DofM from your_table;
```

Note :-"AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME" should be date type otherwise you need to convert to date type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. It is probably not the most efficient way to get it done but it does work and it gives me what I need. Thank you for the input though. It is always helpful to start explaining something to others. It makes you think through it more yourself.

```
  SELECT
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTID" || ' - ' || "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAME" AS Customer,
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTID" || ' - ' || "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTDESCR" AS Product,
         SUM("AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."QNT1") AS Gallons,
         TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'MON') AS MonthName,
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'DD'))  AS DayOfMonth,
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 1))) AS FY,
         EXTRACT (MONTH FROM(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 1))) AS FM,
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS ("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",1),'Q')) AS FQ,
floor(
  (
  trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME") - 
  case 
  -- if December is current month, than use 1st of this month
  when to_char("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'MM') = 12 then trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'MM')
  -- else, use 1st December of previous year
  else add_months(trunc("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME", 'YYYY'), -1)
  end
  ) / 7
) + 1
AS FW,
         "FC_NAME"."LASTCONAME" AS SalesPerson ,
         TO_NUMBER("AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO") AS InvoiceNumber,
         TO_CHAR("AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",'mm/dd/yyyy') AS InvoiceDate,
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."COMMODITY" AS ProductCategory
    FROM "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW",   
         "AR_TRX_LINE",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER",   
         "AR_CUST",   
         "FC_NAME"  
   WHERE ( "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXHDRIDX" = "AR_TRX_HEADER"."ARTRXHDRIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXLINESEQ" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXLINESEQ" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXHDRIDX" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXHDRIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."ARTRXLINETRXTYPE" = "AR_TRX_LINE"."ARTRXLINETRXTYPE" ) and  
         ( "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAMEIDX" = "AR_CUST"."CUSTNAMEIDX" ) and  
         ( "AR_CUST"."SALESPERSONNAMEIDX" = "FC_NAME"."NAMEIDX" ) 
GROUP BY "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTDESCR",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTNAME",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PRODUCTID",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."CUSTID",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."COMMODITY",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."PSSIZE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."UOM",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."QNTTITLE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."AMTTITLE",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME",   
         "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SODATETIME",   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SALESPERSON",   
         "FC_NAME"."LASTCONAME" 
ORDER BY "AR_TRX_HEADER"."SHIPDATETIME" ASC,   
         "AR_PRODUCT_VIEW"."SONO" ASC
```